# Trouble compiling praat on Windows with cygwin - internal compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, praat, internal-compiler-error

I'm attempting to compile Praat (http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/) with Cygwin. I tried following the instructions on the GitHub page (https://github.com/praat/praat). When I run 'make', several files compile with no problem, but then I get:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -std=gnu99 -municode -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O1 -I ../../sys -I ../../dwsys  -c -o gsl_complex__math.o gsl_complex__math.c
gsl_complex__math.c: In function ‘gsl_complex_log10’:
gsl_complex__math.c:425:3: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
   return gsl_complex_mul_real (gsl_complex_log (a), 1 / log (10.));
   ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'gsl_complex__math.o' failed
make[1]: *** [gsl_complex__math.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Colin/workspace/praat-master/external/gsl'
makefile:14: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried posting a question on the Praat user group with no luck. My suspicion is that it will work with a previous version of x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, but I'm not sure how to identify which version will work, or honestly, how to downgrade. (I'm also not sure what the difference is between x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc and plain ol' gcc.) I'd like to avoid any solution that involves editing the source code because it has clearly been compiled as-is before with no problems.

Any suggestions or pointers is the right direction would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I take it using the pre-compiled binaries is for some reason unacceptable? I only ask because you specifically mention that you do not want to modify the source, in which case you could just use the provided binaries.

Comment: I do want to eventually modify the source; I just don't want to modify it for the purposes of making the compiler happy, given that there exists some compiler setup which is satisfied with it. I checked to see if the compiler would complain about other source files in the project; it does. It's quite a large project.